# How to filter any array by key text(name)?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to filter array by the key's text.

Suppose I have an array like:

```
Array
(
    [FAR] => 
    [NEAR] => 1
    [IMMEDIATE] => 
    [FAR_beacon_location] => 
    [FAR_test] => 
    [FAR_test2] =>     
    [NEAR_test] => 6 
    [NEAR_test2] => 6
)
```

From this array I just want the elements whose key's text starts with `NEAR`.

How do I do that?

Comment: `strpos()` http://www.php.net/function.strpos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this code.

```
   $res_arr = array();
    foreach($my_array as $key=>$val) {
        if(strpos($key, "NEAR") === 0) {
            //Key matches,
            $res_arr[] = $val;

        }
    }

    print_r($res_arr);
```

Comment: Since you have used `strpos` this is will match wherever `NEAR` is found in the key. OP wants it in the begining.

Comment: It is actually checking that the position is 0, so, it would be at the start of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this..

```
<?php
$arr=Array
(
    'FAR' => '',
    'NEAR' => 1,
    'IMMEDIATE' =>'', 
    'FAR_beacon_location' =>'', 
    'FAR_test' => '',
    'FAR_test2' =>'',     
    'NEAR_test' => 6, 
    'NEAR_test2' => 6
);

foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
{
if(substr($k, 0, 4)!='NEAR')
{
unset($arr[$k]);
}
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [NEAR] => 1
    [NEAR_test] => 6
    [NEAR_test2] => 6
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function is_NEAR($var)
{
    return strpos($var, "NEAR") === 0;
}

print_r(array_flip(array_filter(array_flip($arr), "is_NEAR")));
```

Comment: thanks for help, just wanted to know among these all solution which one is faster?

Comment: I think that Kumar's and Shankar's solutions will run more or less at the same time and both will be faster than mine.

Comment: there are many problems with this - if values are not scalar, you will get warnings and not not all elements in result array. Also if some values are the same, keys will be lost

Comment: @dev-null-dweller didn't understand your first point and you're right about the second - but it shouldn't be a problem assuming the OP eventually wants only the values.

Comment: As for first problem: `$arr = array('key' => array(), 'key2' => new stdClass);`

Comment: @dev-null-dweller You're right about the first point as well :)

Answer (score -1):

```
    $array=Array
  (
    [FAR] => 
    [NEAR] => 1
    [IMMEDIATE] => 
    [FAR_beacon_location] => 
    [FAR_test] => 
    [FAR_test2] =>     
    [NEAR_test] => 6 
    [NEAR_test2] => 6
  )

   foreach($array as $key=>$value)
  {
      if(strpos($key,"NEAR")==0)
    {
          // do your task
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the same answer what `kumar_v` posted.