# php partial key search in multi-dimentional array and remove obsolete array level

Tags: php, arrays, partial

After looking at many of the already asked questions on php array's I still cant resolve my issue.

My goal is to search an array for partial match and store these results to a new array. The data I'm working with is country information, region information and city information.

I have 3 SQL queries that return data like:
[name][action][value]
amsterdam,city,amsterdam
nederland,country,NL
netherlands,country,NL

The results are retrieved and then merged into an array with

```
$smartsearcharray = array();
array_push($smartsearcharray, $results_countries);
array_push($smartsearcharray, $results_provinces);
array_push($smartsearcharray, $results_cities);
```

However the array looks like

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => andorra
                [action] => country
                [value] => AD
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => argentina
                [action] => country
                [value] => AR
            )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => canillo
                [action] => province
                [value] => AD-02
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => andorra la vella
                [action] => province
                [value] => AD-07
            )
```

Attempts to merge array 0 and array 1, because they contain the same structure failed with RecursiveIteratorIterator

I tried to array_walk recursively, using strpos, preg_grep and combinations but they fail often due to the extra array dimention.

Any suggestions for functions or techniques I should use to get this working?

Many thanks

/edit: **Solution**

```
$res_arr = array();

foreach($smartsearcharray as $item)
{
    if(stripos($item['name'], $search_word) !== false) {

    $res_arr[] = array(
            'name'      => $item['name'],
            'action'    => $item['action'],
            'value'     => $item['value']
            );
    }
}

print_r($res_arr);
```

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20919377/270037

Comment: So, are you trying to merge the three arrays? Combine them into one array, instead of adding them to a new one? array_merge() may be what you're looking for: http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Can't you request/fetch the records from your datasource in a more convinient format?

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I have the simpler array now which is nice.

Comment: I added the php code, however this does match the correct key "name" but does not give me an option to get the "action" and "value" that are stored in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part 1, solving the array via the array merge instead of array_push

```
$results_countries = $this->model_search_smartsearch->buildCountries();
$results_provinces = $this->model_search_smartsearch->buildProvinces();
$results_cities = $this->model_search_smartsearch->buildCities();

$smartsearcharray = array();
$smartsearcharray = array_merge($results_countries, $results_provinces, $results_cities );
```

Part 2, searching the array value, and if it matches store the information in a smaller /new array

```
$res_arr = array();

foreach($smartsearcharray as $item)
{
    if(stripos($item['name'], $search_word) !== false) {

    $res_arr[] = array(
            'name'      => $item['name'],
            'action'    => $item['action'],
            'value'     => $item['value']
            );
    }
}

print_r($res_arr);
```